# Eclipse won't start up with Java installed already

Tags: java, eclipse

I have JDK installed, however when I try to install Eclipse standard edition I get: "A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse." Is it because my JDK is outdated?

Comment: Make sure your java environment variable be setted. Can you use java command in command line?

Comment: @nosille Check which version of JAVA is required for eclipse in "eclipse.ini" file and install that. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the path of your Java installation (e.g. `D:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.6.0_31`).

Or you can set the path to the VM in the `eclipse.ini` file in your Eclipse installation, e.g.:

```
-vm
D:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javaw.exe
```

It's better to set both.

Comment: There was a problem with the dir actually. Thank you anyhow.